# How can I use timespan for each row of the sql table and sum it all up afterwards?

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm doing payroll system log-in and log-out system. To get the interval between two different time I used timespan but I need to use it in every single row of an employee so that I could add it all up for the whole month.
This is my code for getting the timespan of a specific row:

```
             DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(label9.Text);
             DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(label10.Text);
             TimeSpan total = dt2 - dt1;
```

Label9.Text and Label10.Text is invisible in the forms, whenever I click a specific row in the gridview the time in and time out of the specific row will insert to that labels so I could get the timespan.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: How can I use timespan for each row in the sql table so I can add it all up afterwards?

Comment: Well I'd do that server side with a query ,myself. If for some reason it had to be client side, then Linq on the data source that you are populating the labels with. Oh and where's the sum in your code?

Comment: Can u explain how: `To get the interval between two different time I used timespan`, some codes make it more clear.

Comment: I mean, what is the actual problem? Creating the table? Summing timestamps? Reading from the database at all?

Comment: TimeSpan you have is clear enough isn't it?

Comment: What is the structure of your table? U can simply use `sum` in your sql query.

Comment: `SELECT user_id, SUM(timespan) time_worked FROM myTable GROUP BY user_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing TimeSpans in c#, one way is

```
TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan(0);

foreach(var something in somethings)
{
   totalTime = totalTime.Add(new TimeSpan(something.end - something.start);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To summing datetimes to timespan, you can use something like,

```
string startTime = "7:00 AM";
string endTime = "2:00 PM";

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));
```

Comment: Sure... I didn't get his problem though